# A single python loop from zero to n to zero

Tags: python, loops

Is there a Pythonesque way to create a loop that traverses a range from 0 to n and then back to 0?
I could just create 2 loops (one forward and one reverse), but I'm looking for single loop.

My goal is to have an infinite loop that counts from 0 to 1024 to 0.

Comment: "My goal is to have an infinite loop that counts from 0 to 1024 to 0" - that doesn't sound infinite to me.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe it keeps going back and forth in the range infinitely?

Comment: @user2357112 0 to 1024 to 0 and repeat.

Comment: @ChristianDean Exactly, repeat the range infinitely.

Comment: @rdagger Well I think Willem Van Onsem has edited his answer to show how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools` for that:

If you want to go to 1024 and back **once**, you can use:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(range(0,1024),range(1024,0,-1)):
    print(i)
```

In case you will need this quite often, you can use a function to generate the iterable:

```
def range_back(start,end):
    return chain(range(start,end),range(end,start,-1))
```

and use it like:

```
for i in range_back(0,1024):
    print(i)
```

Or if you want to do this an infinite amount of times:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

for i in cycle(chain(range(0,1024),range(1024,0,-1))):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I believe you meant `print(i)` in your first and last examples instead of `print(x)`. No?

Comment: @ChristianDean: yes. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 3):

`chain` two iterables:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.chain(range(1+n), reversed(range(n))):
    do_whatever(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want **infinite** loop:

```
start = 0
end = 1024

i = start
while True:
   print(i)
   if i==end:  
      increment = -1
   elif i==start:
      increment = 1
   i += increment
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a solution without using itertools:

```
while True:
    for i in range(1025) + range(1025)[::-1]:
        print i
```

Range is a generator in python 3, so cast it a list before adding or reversing it. Also, use parentheses on print i:

```
while True:
    for i in list(range(1025)) + list(range(1025))[::-1]:
        print(i)
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range', doesn't work in Python 3.4 (does work in 2.7).

Comment: That is a very cool solution for me since it doesn't require an import and is very easy to read.  I made a slight modification because I only want a single zero and 1024 per loop:  `for i in list(range(0, 1024)) + list(range(1024,0,-1)):`